# Prolog unification doesn't evaluate arithmetic expression

Tags: prolog

Suppose, I wanted to write a program in prolog, which accepts a number input X, and outputs all value pairs for which the sum is X.

```
some_pred(X,X1,X2) :-
    X1 + X2 = X.
```

This does not work, because `X1 + X2` is not evaluated arithmetically.

```
some_pred(X,X1,X2) :-
    Xtemp is X1 + X2,
    Xtemp = X.
```

The other option I have also doesn't work, because `X1` and `X2` are not instantiated.
How would someone solve this?

Comment: Are all the numbers integers >= 0? Or >= 1?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, unification doesn't evaluate arithmetic expressions, and if it did that wouldn't help you because X1 and X2 are undefined so adding them together is meaningless.

You need either to write a search yourself such as a brute force nested loop:

```
sum_a_b(X, A, B) :-
    between(1, X, A),
    between(1, X, B),
    X is A + B.
```

Or a more nuanced one where you encode something about arithmetic into it,  start with 1+(X-1) and then (2+X-2), etc:

```
sum_a_b(X, A, B) :-
    between(0, X, A),
    B is X - A.
```

Or more generally, learn about `clpfd` ([link1](https://www.swi-prolog.org/man/clpfd.html), [link2](https://www.metalevel.at/prolog/clpz)) which can do arithmetic evaluating and solving for missing variables in equations, as well as searching through *finite domains* of possible values:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

sum_a_b(X, A, B) :-
    [A, B] ins 1..X,
    X #= A + B.

? sum_a_b(5, A, B), label([A, B]).
A = 1,
B = 4 ;

A = 2,
B = 3 ;

...
```

NB. I'm assuming positive integers, otherwise with negatives and decimals you'll get infinite pairs which sum to any given X.

Comment: Why `[A, B] ins 1..X`? This constrains the usage to a given `X`.

Comment: @false because clpfd requires finite domains and I want OP to see some integer answers instead of returned constraints, there isn't likely to be an answer in the billions + billions = 5 region. OP asked for an answer with a given X. As far as I can tell "the most general query" is basically never of any interest to me; "all things which could be a CSV line", "all numbers and all the pairs which add up to them" are too many things to ever want to ask about.

Comment: *"the most general query" is basically never of any interest to me* It is in case you try to debug a program. It isn't for the final program.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something very similar, using a list:

```
pos_ints_sum(Sum, L) :-
    compare(C, Sum, 1),
    pos_ints_sum_(C, L, Sum).

% 0 means the list has ended
pos_ints_sum_(<, [], 0).
% 1 means there is only 1 possible choice
pos_ints_sum_(=, [1], 1).
pos_ints_sum_(>, [I|T], Sum) :-
    % Choose a number within the range
    between(1, Sum, I),
    % Loop with the remainder
    Sum0 is Sum - I,
    pos_ints_sum(Sum0, T).
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
?- pos_ints_sum(5, L).
L = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1] ;
L = [1, 1, 1, 2] ;
L = [1, 1, 2, 1] ;
L = [1, 1, 3] ;
L = [1, 2, 1, 1] ;
L = [1, 2, 2] ;
L = [1, 3, 1] ;
L = [1, 4] ;
L = [2, 1, 1, 1] ;
L = [2, 1, 2] ;
L = [2, 2, 1] ;
L = [2, 3] ;
L = [3, 1, 1] ;
L = [3, 2] ;
L = [4, 1] ;
L = [5].
```

Note: `X` is a poor choice of variable name, when e.g. `Sum` can easily be used instead, which has far more meaning.